# What do I get out of this equation and how?

Tags: pleasedonttouchanything

My math is a bit rusty and I'm lazy.
What do I get out of this equation and how?
[image: (8x+3y+67)/sqrt(8^2+3^2)=d]
Please keep spoilers in minimium. I don't actually even want to know what the result is for.

In case the tag is hard to read, the name of the game is *Please, Don't Touch Anything!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was overthinking it.
The point is not to solve the equation in any way, shape or form. Instead...

> There are two sets of numbers that can be extracted from the 'equation'. The numbers above the line and the numbers below it. In other words, **8367** and **8232**.

As for the use...

> Once you reveal a numpad, you can use those numbers to reveal two additional sets of control.

Comment: Thank you, [Rubber Duck](http://lists.ethernal.org/oldarchives/cantlug-0211/msg00174.html).

Comment: The equation is actualy rather boring, when [plotted out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%288x%2B3y%2B67%29%2Fsqrt%288%5E2%2B3%5E2%29). Unless the *d* denotes some special notation, like derivate or diameter. But it doesn't seem to make sense.